# Access to Asset in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

What's proper way to access assets in expo?

I tried this:

```
await Asset.loadAsync(require('file:///assets/data/catalog.json'));
```

Error:

> Unable to resolve "file:///assets/data/catalog.json"

Then I tried this:

```
await Asset.loadAsync(require('../../../assets/data/catalog.json'));
```

Error:

> Module "[object Object]" is missing from the asset registry

Then I tried this:

```
await Asset.loadAsync('../../../assets/data/catalog.json');
```

Error:

> Error: Unable to download file: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=../../../assets/data/catalog.json, NSErrorFailingURLKey=../../../assets/data/catalog.json, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("BackgroundDownloadTask <4AFE570E-3E85-4D12-B9F1-A0C14DA846D0>.<1>"), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundDownloadTask <4AFE570E-3E85-4D12-B9F1-A0C14DA846D0>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}

Comment: As this file is not an image or any other static file that needs to preload, maybe you can just import the file ? `import data from '../../../assets/data/catalog.json';`

Comment: Or did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: @HichamELBSI, I have json and xml files. Your workaround can load json files, but not xml. I want to understand how to use Asset in expo.

Comment: I was getting the second of these errors because the _actual contents_ of the JSON file were being parsed during the `require()` as the value in `[object Object]`. Changing the file extension to something else (e.g. `.txt`) allowed `expo-asset` to function as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them to metro-config.js first and exclude json from `sourceExts` as well

```js
config.resolver.assetExts.push("json");
config.resolver.sourceExts = config.resolver.sourceExts.filter(
  (ext) => ext !== "json"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed!

I needed to read `.txt` file from the `assets/` folder. Here is how I updated metro config [following the expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#assets).

```js
config.resolver.assetExts.push("txt");
```

Now on my codebase i can load it with

```js
const helloAsset = Asset.fromModule(
  require("../assets/hello.txt")
);
```

You can put whatever extension you want.